# Übersetzung von "in each turn"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> Two players play a game in which they take turns asking each other a question. **In each turn**, the player whose turn it is asks the other player any question he wants.

Im [Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-german/turn) kann man deutsche Ausdrücke für "to take turns" oder "whose turn it is" finden, aber es ist davon nicht klar, wie man "in each turn" übersetzen kann.

> Zwei Spieler spielen ein Spiel, in dem sie einander abwechselnd eine Frage stellen. In jeder ___ stellt der Spieler, der dran ist, dem anderen Spieler eine beliebige Frage.

Passt "Reihe" oder "Runde" hier?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolut. Aber hier sind zwei Arten von *turns* im Spiel:

> in jeder Runde (= in each turn)

ist die typische Formulierung in Spielanleitungen u.ä.
Eine *Runde* bedeutet dabei so viel wie "jeder Spieler einmal".
Das zugrundeliegende Bild dabei ist *alle Spieler sitzen um einen Tisch* -> wenn jeder Spieler einmal dran war, ging man gedacht auch einmal um den Tisch herum.

Spricht man dagegen von einzelnen Spielern, sind sie

> an der Reihe

Hier bilden die Spieler eine *Sequenz oder Folge* und jeder Spieler hat eine Position in dieser Reihe, die man gedanklich entlanggeht. Also ist ein Spieler *an der Reihe*, wenn seine Position erreicht ist.

---

Absolutely. But you have two types of *turns* here:

> in jeder Runde (= in each turn)

Is the typical phrase found in game instructions and similar.
A *Runde* means roughly "each player once".
The mental image is *all players sitting around a table* -> if it has been every player's turn, you went round the table once.

If you talk about *individual players*, they are

> an der Reihe

The underlying image is *a sequence or row of players*, each individual player has a position in this sequence which you move along. And if it his turn, you have reached his position in the row.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>English version [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/revisions/25139/3).</sup>

Im Kontext von (Brett-)Spielen spricht man auch vom "Zug".

> Du bist am Zug!

heißt, dass man dran ist. Es wird üblicherweise bei Spielen benutzt, bei denen man tatsächlich Dinge bewegt (zieht), z. B. Figuren oder Karten. Der Begriff wird aber auch breiter verwendet¹.

Die zweite Hälfte deines Beispiels würde ich so übersetzen:

> Der Spieler, der am Zug ist, stellt dem anderen Spieler eine beliebige Frage.

Bezüglich deines Übersetzungsversuchs insgesamt: Selbst, wenn man Stephies Wortübersetzung, die hier besser passt, verwendet, ist er nicht sehr schön. Es gibt Redundanzen (auch schon in deiner englischen Version, aber verschlimmert durch wörtliche Übersetzung): Der zweite Satz gibt keine neue Information (außer vielleicht "beliebig", das man auch leicht im ersten Satz unterbringen kann), und der erste Satz enthält dreimal "-spiel-", was schlechter Stil ist.

Ich würde sowas in der Art bevorzugen:

> Zwei Personen spielen Frag-mich-was: Sie fragen einander abwechselnd, was immer² sie wollen.

Wie man den Satz nun ausschmückt, hängt vom Kontext ab, den du nicht nennst. Geht es hier um Regeln, eine Erzählung, einen Bericht, …? "Frag-mich-was" ist ein erfundener Spielname, um diese Variante anbieten zu können.

---

1. Die Wendung "Du bist am Zug!" kann man immer dann benutzen, wenn jemand mit etwas dran ist.
2. Beachte, dass "immer" hier wichtig ist: "[…], was sie wollen." würde sagen, dass die Spieler sich gegenseitig fragen, was sie *sich* wünschen.

Comment: Nicht Suchmaschinen- oder Google-spezifisch, aber https://www.quantcast.com/german.stackexchange.com zeigt für alle Besucher, daß etwa 40% aus den deutschsprachigen Ländern kommen.

Comment: @Raphael: Wenn du eh schon eine englische Version hast, spricht nichts dagegen, beide Varianten in der Antwort anzubieten.

Comment: @chirlu Danke! (Nach Genuss der Metadiskussion denke ich, dass die einzig spannende Nenngröße die Anzahl der Besucher, die kein oder nur schlecht Englisch können, relevant ist. Wenn man annimmt, dass der typische Westeuropäer Englisch zumindest halbwegs lesen kann, ist das aktuell ne kleine Zielgruppe. Mag aber ne self-fulfilling prophecy sein.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Das finde ich doof. Entweder, oder.

Answer (score 0):

Ergänzend erwähnt sei noch, dass [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=in%20each%20turn) "to ask each in turn" als "reihum fragen" übersetzt.
Darauf basierend eine mögliche Variante für deinen Satz:

> Reihum stellen die beiden Spieler sich gegenseitig eine beliebige Frage.
>   Reihum stellen die Spieler einem anderen Spieler eine beliebige Frage.